# Laravel firing deleted event even though model is already (soft) deleted

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to perform some additional cleanup code when a model that allows soft deletes is deleted.

I've hooked the "deleted" event to perform this cleanup code as follows:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::deleted( function ($mymodel) { <cleanup code here> } );
}
```

However I've found that if delete is called on an already deleted model, the delete event is fired again. I would expect there to be a check in the framework that prevents this, but it would appear not to cater for soft deleted models?

**EDIT: I'm not so much wanting to have a discussion around whether calling delete on a soft deleted record should / should not fire the delete event a second time. I guess there will be a variety of opinions on that. The fact is it currently does and my requirement is it doesn't, so it's more the next part of this question around how I robustly implement a check for that which I need some help with:**

If I have to implement my own check for this, is it safe just to override the delete method on the model - or are there other ways a model can be deleted?? My concern over this point was why I listen for the deleted event to run the clean up code in the first place - rather than override the delete method and place my clean-up code after the call to parent::delete(), as I figured the delete event should be called regardless of how the delete of a model is initiated (if there is indeed more than one way?).

Comment: What's the reason you call `delete()` on an already-deleted model in the first place?

Comment: Yes it's something I've come across when building/debugging the front end so agree not something that should be occurring in the first place. However I'm using the delete event I guess in place of something I traditionally might have done via database trigger, so I want the database and object model to be solid and reliable and not vulnerable to bugs in the front end. I'm kind of viewing it like a property setter which traditionally would check the value of the property isn't already X before setting the value to X and possibly firing off changed events etc.

Answer (score 0):

The responsability of allowing a certain method in a class relies to the allowed triggers, so you shouldn't enable such mechanism in views.

The 'deleted' status of a record defines by itself that the code/view wouldn't expose the object to a 'delete' message, unless it has another behavoir/rule that allows that in the domain. It's you defining the rules of the object domain, so it is you to decide when it could happen or not.

As example, soft-deleting may allow a second delete call to hard-delete a record, for instance, so the FW shouldn't limit the call.

Comment: I understand you are making a general argument and I'd agree in some cases, but feel it's a bit of a stretch in this situation as soft deleting a record is well defined behaviour and the event fires to indicate the record has changed state. If it's already in a deleted state and you delete it again, it seems wrong that another deleted event would fire as the second call didnt change the state of the record. The forceDelete method exists if you want to hard-delete the record. Also if you delete a model that doesn't use soft deletes more than once, the second call will not fire the events.

Comment: A soft-deleted record can be found, and is the spected behavoir, because you can handle that record by, as example, recalling the record. As far it is reachable, it will be prone to receive message. The point is 'delete' is an acceptable message for a soft-deleted record, in the other hand a hard-deleted record does not exist